# How to 'record' a UIBezierPath to be able to playback a stroked drawing path

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, uibezierpath

In my current iOS app, the user is able to draw with their finger by using a UIBezierPath with smoothing the path; this is pretty simple however. What I would like to know, is if it's possible to record the path, the dots, and the color associated for the path and dots for when the user lifts up their finger and changes pencil colors. My goal then is that a play button would then playback everything they just created in real time, and would be sped up with an animation in case they took several minutes drawing.

I appreciate your responses. Here's the code I'm currently using for drawing (not the best code):

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIBezierPath *path;
@property uint ctr;

@end

@implementation DrawViewController
{
    CGPoint pts[4];
}

- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    self.ctr = 0;
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    pts[0] = [touch locationInView:self.drawImage];
}

- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint p = [touch locationInView:self.drawImage];
    self.ctr++;
    pts[self.ctr] = p;

    if (self.ctr == 3)
    {
        pts[2] = CGPointMake((pts[1].x + pts[3].x)/2.0, (pts[1].y + pts[3].y)/2.0);
        [self.path moveToPoint:pts[0]];
        [self.path addQuadCurveToPoint:pts[2] controlPoint:pts[1]];
        //[self.drawImage setNeedsDisplay];
        pts[0] = pts[2];
        pts[1] = pts[3];
        self.ctr = 1;
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),
        ^{
            UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.drawImage.bounds.size, NO, 0.0);

            [self.drawImage.image drawAtPoint:CGPointZero];
            [[UIColor colorWithRed:self.red green:self.green blue:self.blue alpha:1.0] setStroke];
            [self.path stroke];
            self.drawImage.image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
            UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

            [self.path removeAllPoints];
            self.ctr = 0;
        });
    }
}

- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    if (self.ctr == 0)
    {
        [self.path moveToPoint:pts[0]];
        [self.path addLineToPoint:pts[0]];
    }
    else if (self.ctr == 1)
    {
        [self.path moveToPoint:pts[0]];
        [self.path addLineToPoint:pts[1]];
    }
    else if (self.ctr == 2)
    {
        [self.path moveToPoint:pts[0]];
        [self.path addQuadCurveToPoint:pts[2] controlPoint:pts[1]];
    }

    self.ctr = 0;

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),
    ^{
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.drawImage.bounds.size, NO, 0.0);

        [self.drawImage.image drawAtPoint:CGPointZero];
        [[UIColor colorWithRed:self.red green:self.green blue:self.blue alpha:1.0] setStroke];
        [self.path stroke];
        self.drawImage.image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

        [self.path removeAllPoints];
        self.ctr = 0;
    });
}
```

Comment: Yes, that is possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I would do would be to create a custom object that represents a single "segment" of your drawing. (Let's call it a "BezierSegment".) From a quick glance, it looks like you're using quadratic Bezier segments. So create an object that saves the 3 control points for the bezier and the color used to draw it. Each time you draw a new "segment", create one of these objects and add it to a mutable array of segment objects.

Then you could loop through your array of BezierSegment objects, create BezierPath objects out of each one, and draw it to the screen in order to recreate it.

You could also save things like line thickness, optional closed paths with a separate pen color, etc.

Comment: Thanks Duncan, this should be some good food for thought! Edit: Would I add the 'segments' in the touches moved and ended methods?

Comment: I haven't thought about it in detail. Off the top of my head, I'd say yes, add the segments at the same spot in your code where you're creating CGPaths and drawing now.

Comment: Duncan, wouldn't it be necessary to store the color associated with the segment into a dictionary? Each dictionary would be made up of the color associated with it, stroke width, and the actual segment. Finally, each dictionary is added to the NSMutableArray? Or is a dictionary unncessary?

Comment: Edit: now that I think of it, you would just add the color, stroke width, and path to an array and then add those arrays to the entire 'container' NSMutableArray?